# How to output a permutation of B such that A is a wiggly?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting

I was faced with the following question:

> Given an unsorted array `B[1 . . 2n+1]` of real numbers, give a linear
>   time algorithm that outputs a permutation `A[1..2n+1]` of `B` such
>   that `A` is a wiggly.

I basically did a merge sort and altered it:

```
 MergeSort(a,n)
      int i=2;
     while (i ≤ n)
     {
       Swap(a[i−1], a[i]);
       i=i+2;
     }
```

But the time complexity is `O(nlogn) + O(n)` (from sorting and from the loop, respectively), which yields `O(nlogn)`. But I want to do it in `O(n)` time.

Should I use counting sort / radix sort / bucket sort to get a linear time and then alter it to get a wiggly array?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a simple linear solution:

```
for i = 2 ... 2 * n - 1:
     if i % 2 == 0 and a[i] < a[i - 1] or i % 2 == 1 and a[i] > a[i - 1]:
         swap(a[i], a[i - 1])
```

Proof of correctness:

Let's use induction:

1. Base case: only one element is processed, no constraints are violated.
2. Step: if `i % 2 == 0`: If we do not swap anything at this step, the prefix remains valid. Otherwise, we have the following situation: `a[i - 2] >= a[i - 1] > a[i]`. When we make a swap, we can see that the constraints are not violated for the `i - 2` and `i - 1` elements, and the last position is fixed. For an odd `i`, the situation is similar.

Answer (score -1):

Here is the C++ Implementations of the above mentioned algorithm.

```
 #include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void swap(int& a,int& b){
a=a+b;
b=a-b;
a=a-b;
}

int main() {
    int*B ;
    int n;
    cin>>n ; n=2*n;
    B=new int[n] ;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        cin>>B[i] ;
    }

    for(int i=1;i<n;i++){
        if(i%2==0&&B[i]>B[i-1])
            swap(B[i],B[i-1]);
            else if(i%2==1&&B[i]<B[i-1])
            swap(B[i],B[i-1]);


    }

    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        cout<<B[i]<<" ";
    }
    return 0;
}
```